# Что делать, если не получил ответ на вопрос

Tags: обсуждение

Ну, есть один вопрос на который я так и не получил ответ. Есть ли способ "так сказал пропиарить" свой вопрос, или перезадать его заново, что бы он оказался снова в списке первых?

Answer (score 4):

Вариантов несколько:

- Отредактировать, добавить деталей, чтобы было проще дать ответ - [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
- Объявить конкурс, если достаточно репутации - [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Или всё сразу.